# Ruby: How do I add methods to Object? (or simply Extend the object class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

I want to extend Object to add a few methods.

so I can do `@object.table_name` rather than `@object.class.name.tableize`

and similar things like that.

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8, so maybe this sort of thing would go in the lib folder as a module? I don't know.

Comment: `Object` isn't the class you want to modify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# object.rb
class Object
  def table_name
    self.class.name.tableize
  end
end
```

put it into `/config/initializers` or into `lib` folder (in this case you'll need to include it in `ApplicationController`).

Comment: The alternative (so long as the method doesn't already exist) is to put the method in a module, and include the module in a class).

Answer (score 1):

An idiom you'll sometimes see for delegating instance methods to the class is just that:

```
delegate :table_name, :to => 'self'
```